# Rails JS Response, render both status and template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, rendering, partial

In my current rails app I'm using an [ajax uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) library that requires you respond with json `{success:true}` to indicate a file was uploaded successfully.

In my app the files are images, and after upload I would like to add this to the page. Normally I would do something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @resource, :notice => 'Created.' }
  format.js
end
```

In the above example my JS response would render the appropriate template, such as `create.js.erb` which might say something like...

```
$('#resources').append('<%= escape_javascript( render '@resource' ) %>');
```

This is how I have done things like Ajax comments etc. in the past. Now, to get the uploader working my `respond_to` block currently does this:

```
format.js { render :json => { :success => true } }
```

This makes the uploader work but seems to preclude me adding rendered partials to the page like I normally would with an Ajax response.

**My question is, is there any way to accomplish both?** If not, how would you populate the page with rendered objects after they have been successfully created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do both directly from the controller or using view templates.  It looks like ajax uploader is expecting a response that can be parsed as JSON, so adding any other response using a template (which would mean not doing `format.js { render :json => { :success => true }}`) will not send back JSON as the response body.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/client/fileuploader.js#L268) for the plugin, you can see that you can define a method to run `onComplete` which will give you the JSON response.

This is untested, but should get you close.  So you if extend your JSON response like

```
format.js do
  partial = render_to_string @resource
  render :json => { :success => true, :partial => partial }
end
```

Then in your javascript on the page when you setup your ajax uploader, add the callback

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
  element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
  action: '/upload',
  onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    $('#resources').append(responseJSON.partial);
  }
});
```

Comment: This idea works. I didn't know about `render_to_string`, but in testing I found I could also use `.getScript` in the callback to retrieve the partial. Your method is cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: One note... by default `escape_javascript` is not available to the controller, and it's not needed because the `render :json` method does it anyway.

Comment: cool, glad it helps.  Makes sense that `escape_javascript` doesn't work there, don't know what I was thinking.  Thanks for the feedback on the answer